# How to alias/override the HTTP path of a default remote-method in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I have a model `players` which is extended from the base model `User`.
The `player` model inherits all the remote-methods from the base model. A new 'User' can be created by a `POST /user` in the base model.
My custom model `player` also inherits this method.
In my use-case i want this method to be `POST /signup`. How could i do this?

```
"methods": {
    "signup": {
      "accepts": [],
      "returns": [
        {
          "arg": "user",
          "type": "object",
          "root": false,
          "description": "the data about created user"
        }
      ],
      "description": "User signup",
      "http": [
        {
          "path": "/",
          "verb": "post"
        }, {
          "path": "/signup",
          "verb": "post"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

With the snippet above in the model.json file for remote-method i was able to expose two endpoints for user creation. But can i override the path for `POST /user` to `POST /signup`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in loopback to achieve this. Even if you create a new custom remote method, its endpoint would always be prefixed with `/user`.